# emacs error in Ubuntu of MobaXterm

Tags: 18.04, emacs

I am using Ubuntu on MobaXterm Personal Edition v21.2 on Windows 10. Whenever I open emacs editor, it opens and works fine, but I keep getting `dconf-CRITICAL **` with following error lines multiple times in terminal :

```
unable to create file '/home/MyUsername/.cache/dconf/user': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
```

I am not an expert with Ubuntu, so am not sure what to try. For more details, `cat /etc/os-release` gives me this :

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
```

Comment: It sounds like a simple permissions problem - likely because you performed an operation as root in your home directory. Please [edit] your question to include the output of `namei -l ~/.cache/dconf/user`

Comment: I did "chown" following https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/509194/488405 and it works. I am not sure if it's the best solution, and that if it might create any other issues...